bazel run does NOT overwrite the file written out by cc_binary
I have a cc_binary named my_prog defined in my BUILD file. In my_prog I write out a file named out.txt.
When I run the binary with bazel run //:my_prog if out.txt does not exist then a new file out.txt is written out in the output directory of bazel.
However, if out.txt exists already in the output directory, it does not get overwritten when I run bazel run //:my_prog.
Is there something I am missing?

Check that the working directory is what you expect.
From https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#running-executables
"When the binary is not a test, the current working directory will be the runfiles tree of the binary."
Try running the program directly out of bazel-bin
